# Is it possible to run MAFFT through python sys module

Tags: python, command, line, sys

Is it possible to run MAFFT commands like 'mafft_exe', 'in_file' through the Python sys.argv module?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but based on the limited context you've provided I'm assuming that you're using something like biopython as a wrapper to MAFFT, and you're trying to change certain arguments that get passed to the `MafftCommandline` class.

In the [biopython docs](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.Applications._Mafft.MafftCommandline-class.html), the MAFFT executable wrapper is invoked like this:

```
mafft_cline = MafftCommandline(mafft_exe, input=in_file)
```

Python's arguments-handling module is `sys.argv`. It is a list, and you can access its arguments by numeric index.

So supposing you wanted to pass certain values to the MAFFT wrapper class from the command line, you could do it like this:

```
import sys
from Bio.Align.Applications import MafftCommandline

# Replace with actual binary location, or implement it as an arg
MAFFT_EXE_LOCATION = "/opt/local/mafft"

def other_code(mafft):
    # Do other stuff with mafft here, now that it's configured
    pass


def invoke_mafft(input_filename):
    mafft_cline = MafftCommandline(MAFFT_EXE, input=input_file)
    other_code(mafft_cline)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        input_filename = sys.argv[1]
        invoke_mafft(input_filename)
    except IndexError:
        print("USAGE: {} <in_file>".format(sys.argv[0]))
```

This is just a starting point. What you actually end up doing with the class is up to you.